# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:buildInfoDebugLoader' in Android

Tags: android

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:buildInfoDebugLoader'.
```

> Exception while doing past iteration backup : Source G:\AndroidStudioProjects\Registrazione\app\build\intermediates\builds\debug\33974812191121\classes.dex and destination G:\AndroidStudioProjects\Registrazione\app\build\intermediates\builds\debug\33974812191121\classes.dex must be different

when i compile project it say this , but after it was work i had change only one line of code

build grandle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.rober.registrazione"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: Post the gradle file.

Comment: where is `build.gradle`

Comment: do you find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

I solved this issue by Build -> Rebuild Project  and then Run again.

Also I think newly added menu Run -> Clean and Rerun should also fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and I solved simply **deleting** the folder:

```
G:\AndroidStudioProjects\Registrazione\app\build\intermediates\builds\debug\33974812191121
```

Not sure if it's the correct way but for me it worked like a charm !
Hope it will the same for you

Answer (score 1):

This problem is commonly caused by having 2 different Gradle operations on the same project (such as Build Projetct and Run/quick-Run). This causes two processes writting the same destination file, and causes the second process to fail.

To fix the problem, rename/delete the file, then give Android Studio one command again.